# How to create stacked bars on some conditional statements in Spotfire

Tags: data-analysis, spotfire

I am new to spotfire. I have a scenario that I should create a stacked bars based on the days. the days column contain numeric values. if days = 0 -> met, if days>0 not met and if days?<0 advanced. based on this condition I need to generate stacked bars using spotfire.

can anyone help me please ? I tried some conditional concepts which did not worked for me.

Comment: Insert this calculated column: `case when [days] = 0 then "met" when [days] > 0 then "not met" else "advanced" end`. If you need help creating a bar chart, consider sharing a sample dataset.

Comment: Hi, the sample data is as follows: column name is days_diff, and the values are
-25
-26
-14
163
-19
-11
-18
-18
-21
-11. Please suggest. I tried creating calculated column and it did not worked as expected.

Comment: I think we need some clarification in what you're expecting.  I initially interpreted it as you had three columns, for example, [Customers], [Date_Diff] and [Calendar_Year], and you wanted a bar graph with Calendar_Year across the bottom, the bars' height determined by the count of customers, and the color of the stacked bars determined by the calculated column as @blakeoft indicated.  
Could you go into more details as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Issue resolved. My requirement is to create stacked bars based on days count. days count contains -ve, 0 and +ve numbers. So I have created a calculated 3 columns (for met, not met and advanced) and then I used for graphs.  Thanks a lot blakeoft and Cheslsea.